# how to Use the Android system to decode MP3 and get the PCM data on the fly?

Tags: android

i want to decode the PCM data from MP3 file using  MediaExtractor and MediaCodec , can anyone post me some samples ?

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

There are CTS tests that do this, for a number of different file types. I'd look at some of the older versions of DecoderTest (e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/DecoderTest.java) because the later versions gained a lot of complexity that improved test coverage but made it harder to understand.